# How target a specific custom html tag with jQuery script

Tags: jquery, html, thymeleaf

I am trying to use a jQuery to hide something and show a form in a table, but right now I hide or show everything on my custom tag. How could I make this script only target an ID that I could give to those tag?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hide").click(function() {
    $("p").hide(100);
    $("z").show(100);
  });
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $("p").show(100);
    $("z").hide(100);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <th>début vacance</th>
  <th>fin vacance</th>
  <th>supprimer vacances</th>
  <tr th:each="vacations : ${selectedUser.getVacations()}">
    <td th:utext="${vacations.getStartVacation()} ">...</td>
    <td th:utext="${vacations.getEndVacation()} + ${vacations.id}">...</td>
    <td>
      <p th:text="${vacation.fistname}">...</p>
      <z th:text="${vacations.id}">...</z>
      <button class="hide">Hide</button>
      <button class="show">Show</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

Comment: What's the actual HTML output? I doubt `<z />` is an element that's used within the `table`

Comment: <z> is a custom tag that my jqerry script target, and my probleme is that i don't know how to target specific <z> tag in my table

Comment: @31piy -- i want to be able that my hide or show button only affect the <z> and <p> button in that row, not all the table, i was maybe thinking i could give them an id, but i don't know how to put that in the script

Comment: @31piy no, you cannot invent your own elements, unless you also create your own DOCTYPE which will interpret them dynamically. With HTML5 it's certainly not allowed: https://i.imgur.com/aeAWcYA.png

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This will check the nearest parent tr and find p or z inside this. This will not fail any case if u added multiple container for p also

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".hide").click(function(){
              $(this).parents('tr').find("p").hide(100);
              $(this).parents('tr').find("z").show(100);
          });
          $(".show").click(function(){
              $(this).parents('tr').find("p").show(100);
              $(this).parents('tr').find("z").hide(100);
          });
      });
  </script>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since the buttons and `p` and `z` tags are siblings, you can do something like this to scope the operations to current `td` only:

```
$(".hide").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("p").hide(100);
  $(this).siblings("z").show(100);
});

$(".show").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings("p").show(100);
  $(this).siblings("z").hide(100);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by sibling tags?

Comment: @shas -- By sibling tags, I mean that they have the same parent, i.e. `td`.